# My app always navigates to home screen even though the logged in status is false in react native

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I am trying to set up a authentication such that when user is logged in, then they should be re-directed to home screen else should stay on the login screen in react native, however, as if now, it only re-directs to home screen even though logged in state is false. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Below is my code for App.js

```js
import BottomNavigator from "./src/views/navigation/BottomNavigator";
import OnBoardScreen from "./src/views/screens/OnBoardScreen";
import Login from "./src/views/screens/Login";
import { store } from "./store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkAuthenticationStatus = async () => {
      const isAuthenticated = await AsyncStorage.getItem("KeepLoggedIn");
      setIsLoggedIn(isAuthenticated);
    };

    checkAuthenticationStatus();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor={COLORS.white} barStyle="dark-content" />

        {isLoggedIn ? (
          <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={BottomNavigator} />
            <Stack.Screen name="DetailsScreen" component={DetailsScreen} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        ) : (
          <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
            <Stack.Screen name="BoardScreen" component={OnBoardScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        )}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.stringify/JSON.parse` to set/get boolean to/from storage.

> Async Storage can only store string data, so in order to store object data you need to serialize it first. For data that can be serialized to JSON you can use JSON.stringify() when saving the data and JSON.parse() when loading the data.

See [Usage](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage) for details.